# How to set a moment js date to June 1st of next or this year based on a condition

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to set a date based on the current date. Let's say the name of the variable is validTo.

Condition: validTo date should be set to June 1st of this year if validFrom(today) is less than June 1st(let's say May 31st), else (let's say June 2nd), validTo date should be June 1st of next year(2022).

```
const validFromDate = moment().toDate();

//set this based on a condition

const validToDate =
        moment().month() < 5
          ? moment()
              .set({ month: 5, date: 1 })
              .toDate()
          : moment()
              .set({
                month: 5,
                date: 1,
                year: moment().year() + 1,
              })
              .toDate();
```

Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: For starters, you could condense this to a single `set` statement, and use the ternary operator in there to determine whether to use the current year, or add 1 to it: `year: moment().year() + (moment().month() < 5 ? 0 : 1)`

Comment: can you use this too `moment('06-01', 'MM-DD').year(moment().year() + Number(moment().month() < 5));`